# Directive click getting called twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
mod.directive('mdCheckbox', function(){
        var link = function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
        var inp = element.find('input');

        scope.$watch(function(){
            return ngModel.$viewValue;
        }, function(newVal){
            console.log('newVal: ' + newVal);
            if(newVal){
                inp.attr('checked', 'checked');
            }else{
                inp.removeAttr('checked');
            }
        });

        scope.clickT = function(evt){
            // ** why the need for stopPropagation ?
            evt.stopPropagation();
            console.log('click called');
            if(inp.is(':checked')){ 
                ngModel.$setViewValue(false);
                console.log('set to false');
            }else{
                ngModel.$setViewValue(true);
                console.log('set to true');
            }
        };
    };

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            text: '@mdText'
        },
        template: '<div ng-click="clickT($event)" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/>' +
                    '<span>{{text}}</span></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

});
```

and the html :

```
<md-checkbox md-text="Is Awesome" ng-model="user.isAwesome"></md-checkbox>
```

Now the clickT handler is called twice, and I have to stop propagation on it. But it's not clear to me why that happens. And the second problem is that even though this seems like it works, after a couple of clicks it stops working - the value doesn't change true/false anymore.

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/dswGLFWkXebDjK8QE3ZH?p=preview) a plunkr for testing

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't change the DOM manually because you can use data binding for that. But I won't go into that since it isn't the answer to question you asked.

Problem in your example is code that toggles Checking/Unchecking checkbox. It's not an attribute, it's a property(it can be true/false, not contain a value).

The `checked` attribute doesn't update the `checked` property after initial load. The attribute is in fact related to `defaultChecked` property.

Change it to:

```
if (newVal) {
    inp.prop('checked', true);
} else {
    inp.prop('checked', false);
}
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXAbEm6sAXqQsFWTswRZ?p=preview)

Also, you can remove stopPropagation call.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong about `checked` not being an attribute, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: got my upvote yet because I haven't found another way to call input#$render() method, without writing to model directly.

Comment: @Werlang I meant in jQuery context, read "Attributes vs. Properties" in jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I'm creating the attribute because it's a styled checkbox (the look and feel of material design) so I was thinking that it would be the best way to handle it. If you can suggest a better way of handling it, I'd love to hear it. And thanks for the prop thing .. I thought I tried that in an earlier version.

Comment: @sirrocco You can check out AngularMaterial project: https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.checkbox . Source code if checkbox directive is here: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/checkbox/checkbox.js

Comment: thanks for that, I was aware of it but I figure it's a good way of learning more by doing them myself.

Comment: @sirrocco Sure it is, but it never hurts to peak at open sourced working code when stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

There was something weird about the way you were adding and removing the checked attribute.  Keep it simple and just set the input to true or false.

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZuqcoM5MmwUxHLKumBR2?p=preview)

```
scope.clickT = function(){

                console.log('click called');
                if(inp){ 
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(false);
                    console.log('set to false');
                }else{
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(true);
                    console.log('set to true');
                }
            };
```

Comment: That's plain wrong from an accessibility point of view. You should update checked attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you query `ngModel` instead of `input`.

```
if (ngModel.$viewValue) ...
```

Although I'm not sure what this directive buys you...